# alternative to Tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, tags

What is the alternative to winforms-style `control.Tag` in asp.net?

For example:

```
ListItem li = ListBox1.SelectedItem;    
Product prod = (Product) li.Tag;
```

How can I rewrite this in asp.net?

Comment: what do you want to put in tag?

Comment: Any object for later use. In this case, Product object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there isn't any easy way as far as I know. Because of the stateless nature of the web, you need to rely on your `Session`, `ViewState` or `ControlState` to store those details.

Here's an [explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx) of `ViewState` and `ControlState`.